# How to remove repeated words in string using regular expression in TCL?

Tags: regex

set a "one two one three four five one six six seven two one five four". i want to remove repeated elements from a using regular expression. i have tried  . but no use.

Comment: You said you have tried. What have you tried? Also, what should be the result?

Comment: @Jerry he did post it but on his second edit he deleted it...probably stll editing it

Comment: Clarify what result are you expecting please.

Comment: I want the result with no repeated elements i.e "one two three four five six seven"

Comment: When i try with tcl, i am getting as % set a "one two one three four five one six six seven two one five four"
% set r [regexp (\S+)(?=.*\b\1\b) $a match]
0
% puts $a
one two one three four five one six six seven two one five four
% puts $r
0
% puts $match
can't read "match": no such variable
%

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method without regex:

```
set a "one two one three four five one six six seven two one five four"

set unique [list]

foreach element $a {
    if {[lsearch -exact $unique $element] == -1} {
        lappend unique $element
    }
}

puts $unique
```

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/msPHiVRm)

Or if you have Tcl8.5 and up, you can replace the loop with the below:

```
foreach element $a {
    if {$element in $unique} {
        lappend unique $element
    }
}
```

Or simpler in Tcl8.6 and up, replace the loop with this one liner:

```
lmap x $a {if {$x ni $unique} {lappend unique $x}}
```

If you don't mind about the order of the words, you can simply use the built-in [`lsort`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/lsort.htm) which does not need anything more than:

```
set unique [lsort -unique $a]
```

With all these tools available, I don't think you need regex to do this.

---

One 'simple' alternative with regex:

```
while {[regsub -all {\y((\w+)\y.*?)\y\2\y\s*} $a {\1} a] > 0} {continue}
```

This will replace second occurrences until there are no more.

`\y` is a word boundary (matches between `\w` and either of `^`, `$`, or `\W` regex characters)

`((\w+)\y.*?)` will match and store a word, and also store separately anything until the second occurrence of that stored word at `\y\2\y`.

`\s*` removes any trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerry. I have done using above method. But i particularly want to do in regular expression.

Comment: @KalpanaArunPrasath Any reason why? Tcl's regexp engine is pretty limited. The ideal feature would be a variable length lookbehind, which is available only in C# should you want only the second and subsequent occurrences to be removed, and if you can keep only the last, you will need to be able to use backreferences within a lookahead, which is not possible in Tcl. So you'd have to run a replacement several times as alternative... I have amended the answer with a regexp alternative. `$a` will have the final string.

Answer (score -1):

```
(\S+)(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

You can use this simple regex .Just replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/16

Comment: If you tried this regex, it wouldn't compile correctly in Tcl

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I am new to regular exp. I have tried what you have given. Getting error  as % set a "one two one three four five one six six seven two one five four"
one two one three four five one six six seven two one five four
%  string map [regexp {(\S+)(?=.*\b\1\b)} $a] $a
couldn't compile regular expression pattern: invalid backreference number

Comment: @vks It depends on what the output should be. And you are answering a question without reading the question?

Comment: @Jerry i checked TCL regex.inside `{}` this seems to be a legitimate one.isisn't it?

Comment: @KalpanaArunPrasath try `$1` insead of `\1` or `\2`

Comment: Getting character map unbalanced. %  string map [regexp {(\S+)(?=.*\b\$1\b)} $a] $a
char map list unbalanced
%  string map [regexp {(\S+)(?=.*\b$1\b)} $a] $a
char map list unbalanced
%  string map [regexp {(\S+)(?=.*\b$2\b)} $a] $a
char map list unbalanced
%

Comment: I dint understand the pattern itself. if possible tell me how to work with regex.

Comment: @KalpanaArunPrasath check demo.See right side for explanation